# using perl to connect to apache cassandra 2.0.1

Tags: perl, cassandra

I've been working on Cassandra from the past two weeks and am stuck in a few places i was hoping you could help me out with it.

I've installed the apache-cassandra-2.0.1,perlcassa-master,Perl5.10, Thrift::XS and  Time::HiRes.I am still not able to connect to Cassandra .when i run perl Makefile.PL i get the follow warning

> "Warning: prerequisite Class::Accessor 0 not found. Writing Makefile
>   for perlcassa" Ignoring the warning when i ran my script i got the
>   following error. "Base class package "Class::Accessor" is empty.
>   (Perhaps you need to 'use' the module which defines that package
>   first,or make that module available in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5
>   /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl `enter code
>   here`/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5
>   .).  at /usr/local/share/perl5/Cassandra/Types.pm line 38 BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at
>   /usr/local/share/perl5/Cassandra/Types.pm line 38. Compilation failed
>   in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/Cassandra/Cassandra.pm line 11.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   /usr/local/share/perl5/Cassandra/Cassandra.pm line 11. Compilation
>   failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/perlcassa/Client.pm line
>   18. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/perlcassa/Client.pm line 18. Compilation failed
>   in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/perlcassa.pm line 159. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/perlcassa.pm
>   line 159. Compilation failed in require at ./cassconn.pl line 2. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at ./cassconn.pl line 2."

my script cassconn.pl

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use perlcassa;

    my $result = $obj->exec(
    "SELECT n,ei,toj,sal,d FROM sample.test WHERE n='divya'",
    {key_value => 'n'}
     );
    my $row = $result->fetchone();
    print "Row key, col01: ".$row->{key}.", ".$row->{col01}."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help you, I will explain how I did it.

[Download](https://thrift.apache.org/) and install Thrift compiler on your machine.

Install Thrift library for Perl client application using cpan

> cpan Thrift

Move to the directory you installed Cassandra, there is `interface` directory inside it

> cd /path/to/cassandra/interface/

Then generate Cassandra library for Perl using Thrift compiled you installed earlier

> /path/to/thrift/binary/Thrift --gen Perl cassandra.thrift

It will create a directory `gen-perl` in the present directory, you will need to include it using `use` statement in your Perl scripts. Here's an [example](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftExamples#Perl) script, althou it doesn't work with newest versions of Cassandra and Thrift it is pretty similar, in case if you have issues I provide you with example that work with `Cassandra-2.0.8` and `Thrift-0.9.1`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

# Change for your environment
use lib '/path/to/cassandra/interface/gen-perl';
use Cassandra::Cassandra;
use Cassandra::Constants;
use Cassandra::Types;

use Thrift;
use Thrift::BinaryProtocol;
use Thrift::Socket;
use Thrift::FramedTransport;

use Data::Dumper;

# localhost and 9160 are default in storage conf for rpc listener
my $socket = new Thrift::Socket('localhost', 9160);
my $transport = new Thrift::FramedTransport($socket);
my $protocol = new Thrift::BinaryProtocol($transport);
my $client = new Cassandra::CassandraClient($protocol);

eval {
    $transport->open();
    my $consistency_level = Cassandra::ConsistencyLevel::ONE;
    my $keyspace = 'DEMO';
    my $column_parent = new Cassandra::ColumnParent();
    $column_parent->{column_family} = "User";
    $column_parent->{super_column} = undef;
    $column_parent->{column} = 'age';

    $client->set_keyspace($keyspace);

    my $column = new Cassandra::Column();

    my $row_key = 'Spider-Man';

    $column->{name} = 'first';
    $column->{value} = 'Peter';
    $column->{timestamp} =  time;
    $client->insert($row_key, $column_parent, $column, $consistency_level);

    $column->{name} = 'last';
    $column->{value} = 'Parker';
    $column->{timestamp} =  time;
    $client->insert($row_key, $column_parent, $column, $consistency_level);

    $column->{name} = 'age';
    $column->{value} = '18';
    $column->{timestamp} =  time;
    $client->insert($row_key, $column_parent, $column, $consistency_level);

    $transport->close();
}; if($@){
    warn(Dumper($@));
}
1;
```

It adds an entry to Cassandra keyspace `DEMO` with key `spider-man` and following column values `peter`, `parker`, `18`.

Here is the result of query on `cassandra-cli` after execution of this script:

```
[default@DEMO] list User;
Using default limit of 100
Using default cell limit of 100
(...)
-------------------
RowKey: spidey
=> (name=age, value=18, timestamp=1404222046)
=> (name=first, value=Peter, timestamp=1404222046)
=> (name=last, value=Parker, timestamp=1404222046)
(...)

4 Rows Returned.
Elapsed time: 367 msec(s).
```